# Non-similar Jordan Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

How many non-similar Jordan Forms are there for an **n** × **n** matrix all of whose eigenvalues are identical?

Comment: What are your thoughts about that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm thinking it's just the partition function, the number of ways of partitioning **n** into natural numbers. I also want to prove that no two different arrays, not counting order, of Jordan decomposition are similar.